# Pegar latitude longitude Android - Location == null

Tags: java, android

Estou com problema para pegar a latitude e longitude no Android.
Usando esta função, sempre o "location" retorna "null".

```
public void onCreate() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null) {
        la = location.getLatitude();
        lo = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d("create", "la = " + la + " e lo = " + lo);
        new Thread(localizacao.this).start();
    } else {
        Log.d("update", "location null");
    }
}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você inicia o serviço de localização, ele só vai te retornar uma posição válida depois de ele ter conseguido descobrir a localização do usuário. Tente o seguinte:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,    
                                                        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private Location currentLocation = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Inicializa o objeto e registra os callbacks.
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        //Tentamos nos conectar ao serviço de localização.
        locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       //Disconectamos do serviço de localização quando o app sai do foco.
       locationClient.disconnect();
       super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        //Estamos devidamente conectados ao serviço de localização.
        //Podemos pegar posições a vontade agora.
        //Se você quiser, pode usar uma variavel booleana aqui,
        //para dizer ao seu app que ele pode pegar posições de localização
        //diferentes de null.
        currentLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        //Aqui você pode alterar a variável booleana para seu app não tentar
        //pegar mais posições de localização, embora, caso você tenha se
        //conectado ao serviço, e você tente pegar uma localização,
        //ele irá retornar a última localização disponível.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //O Google Play consegue resolver alguns problemas de conexão com
        //sistema de localização. Aqui a gente verificar se o Google Play
        //tem a solução para o erro que ocorre.
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);              
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 

    }

}
```

Lembrando apenas que esse código utiliza a biblioteca GooglePlayServices.

Nesse código a gente implementa interfaces que são listeners para o estado do sistema de localização do dispositivo. Assim, a gente consegue saber quando o sistema de localização vai nos retornar uma localização válida.

Answer (score 4):

Você não pode pegar a localização assim diretamente, dê uma olhada na documentação: http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

No momento em que você está tentando obter a localização, o dispositivo ainda não a tem para te fornecer, o que ocasiona NullPointer.

Sugiro dar uma lida na documentação para verificar como você pode implementar um LocationListener, onde dentro dele você consegue verificar se possui uma localização a ser retornada, obter atualização de localização utilizando o método onLocationChanged e verificando alterações no status do provider.

Uma implementação abaixo:

```
public class Localizacao implements LocationListener {

    protected static final String TAG = null;
    private Context context;
    private LocationManager lm;
    private Location location;
    private volatile boolean stop = false;
    private static final int UM_SEGUNDO = 1000;
    private int tempoTotalBusca = 10;
    protected ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public Localizacao(Context context) {
        lm = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean estado() {
        return lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    public Location capturarCoordenadaGPS() {

        try {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Looper.myLooper();
                    Looper.prepare();

                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, null,
                            context.getString(R.string.aguarde),
                            true);

                    ativaGPS();
                    Looper.loop();
                }
            }).start();
            // Thread.sleep(10*1000);

            int tempoBusca = 0;

            while (!stop) {
                if (tempoTotalBusca == tempoBusca) {
                    break;
                }

                Thread.sleep(UM_SEGUNDO);
                tempoBusca++;
            }
            return location;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO - Trate a exceção;
        } finally {
            desativaGPS();
            if (progressDialog != null)
                progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void ativaGPS() {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this,
                Looper.myLooper());
        // Looper.loop();
    }

    private void desativaGPS() {
        lm.removeUpdates(Localizacion.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
        stop = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // Provider desabilitado
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // Provider habilitado
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // Status do provider alterado
    }

}
```

Comment: Você poderia dar alguma informação mais relevante aqui? "respostas" só com link tendem se tornar inválidas com o tempo se houver alguma mudança.

Comment: Lucas, tentei usar a classe que você postou, mas continuo recebendo NULL.

<pre><code>public void onCreate() {
  Localiza localiza = new Localiza(getApplicationContext());
  location = localiza.capturarCoordenadaGPS();
  if (location != null) {
   la = location.getLatitude();
   lo = location.getLongitude();
   Log.d("create", "la = " + la + " e lo = " + lo);
  } else {
   Log.d("update", "location null");
  }
 }</code></pre>


Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Você precisa aguardar ter uma localização disponível, coloque um breakpoint dentro do método onLocationChanged e simule uma mudança de localização utilizando o LocationControls do Eclipse.

Comment: Usei a mudança de localização do eclipse e testei no celular. Sem sucesso...

Comment: Matheus, tente fazer o seguinte teste: coloque um breakpoint dentro do método onLocationChanged e depois simule localização pelo Eclipse, tudo estiver correto a execução cairá no breakpoint.

Comment: Lucas, coloquei o breakpoint e está caindo certinho, mas o Location esta NULL.

Comment: Corrigindo Lucas, no onLocationChanged o Location esta correto com a LA/LO, mas o retorno é NULL.

Comment: Bom, se está correto, é só você pegar a propriedade location. Nela estará as coordenadas que você quer. Na verdade, o método onLocationChanged é void, não retorna nada, apenas seta o location atualizado. Sendo assim, é só acessar essa propriedade.

Comment: Tem alguma forma de chamar o onLocationChanged sem realmente mudar a localização? PQ só consigo pegar o Location no onLocationChanged não consigo pegar no capturarCoordenadaGPS.

Comment: Matheus, você deve usar o método getLastKnowLocation().

`LocationManager locationMngr = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); 

Location localizacao = locationMngr .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); // Aqui o parametro é o seu provider, pode ser NETWORK_PROVIDER ou GPS_PROVIDER.`

Answer (score 1):

Nossa, estou com exatamente o mesmo problema, já tentei com tudo GooglePlayServices, direto usando um Listener no método onLocationChanged, e nada, nada consigo um resultado que seja Location diferente de null.
Em alguns aparelhos como um Samsung S2 funciona perfeitamente.

```
// if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
if (isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
    if (location == null) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
        Log.d(Const.TAG, "GPS ENABLED (LocationTracker.java)");
        if (locationManager != null) {
            // even this line it does not work
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

            // this line always returns null, no matter what I do
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }
    }
}
```